# Large discrepancy in `gasUsed` values in near-identical transactions on Hedera - why?

Tags: solidity, rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I have noticed that there is a discrepancy between the amount of gas used
by a transaction is almost identical:

I'm making a call to a smart contract,
with the same parameters twice in a row,
and the only difference between the 2
is that I'm setting `gasLimit` to the exact value
returned by `eth_estimateGas` in the 1st one,
and I'm setting `gasLimit` to `eth_estimateGas * 1.1` in the 2nd one.

```js
    // with exact estimated amount of gas
    const estimatedGas2 = (await expendGasSc.estimateGas.updateState(1_000_000_123n)).toBigInt();
    console.log('estimatedGas2', estimatedGas2);
    const gasLimit2 = estimatedGas2 * 1n;
    console.log('gasLimit2', gasLimit2);
    const txResponse2 = await (await expendGasSc
        .updateState(
            1_000_000_123n,
            { gasLimit: gasLimit2 },
        ))
        .wait();
    const gasUsed2 = txResponse2.gasUsed.toBigInt();
    console.log('gasUsed2', gasUsed2);

    // with 110%  of estimated amount of gas
    const estimatedGas3 = (await expendGasSc.estimateGas.updateState(1_000_000_123n)).toBigInt();
    console.log('estimatedGas3', estimatedGas3);
    const gasLimit3 = estimatedGas3 * 11n / 10n;
    console.log('gasLimit3', gasLimit3);
    const txResponse3 = await (await expendGasSc
        .updateState(
            1_000_000_123n,
            { gasLimit: gasLimit3 },
        ))
        .wait();
    const gasUsed3 = txResponse3.gasUsed.toBigInt();
    console.log('gasUsed3', gasUsed3);
```

Here's the output, which shows that:

- when `gasLimit` is set to 400,000, `gasUsed` is 320,000
- when `gasLimit` is set to 440,000, `gasUsed` is 352,000

```
estimatedGas2 400000n
gasLimit2 400000n
gasUsed2 320000n
estimatedGas3 400000n
gasLimit3 440000n
gasUsed3 352000n
```

Why does the 2nd invocation expend an additional 32,000 in gas?
(I expected the `gasUsed` value to be the same in both cases.)

---

Here's the smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract ExpendSomeGasDemo {
    uint256 public state;

    function updateState(
        uint256 newState
    )
        public
        returns (uint256 updatedState)
    {
        state = newState;
        updatedState = newState;
    }
}
```

Note that this contract is deployed on Hedera Testnet:
[`0x9C58D0159495F7a8853A24574f2B8F348a72424c`](https://hashscan.io/testnet/contract/0.0.4616849)

Note that the Javascript example above is using ethers.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of:
[HIP-185:](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-improvement-proposal/blob/master/HIP/hip-185.md) Smart Contract Service Gas Based Throttling
​

> In order to ensure that the transactions can execute properly it is common to set a higher gas reservation than will be consumed by execution.
> In Ethereum Mainnet the entire reservation is charged to the account prior to execution and then unused portion of the reservation is credited back.
> Ethereum Mainnet, however, utilizes a memory pool and does transaction ordering at block production time, and that allows the block limit to be based only on used gas and not reserved gas.
> ​
> Essentially `gasLimit` refers to the "higher gas reservation",
> and `gasUsed` is refers to the gas "consumed by execution".
> In Ethereum, the calculation is simply:
> ​

```
gasUsed = gasConsumed
```

​
In other words, `gasLimit` **is not** a factor.

However, in Hedera, this isn't possible,
since Hedera's consensus nodes do not make use of a transaction pool,
and then subsequently order transactions within a block.
In fact, Hedera does not even have the concept of blocks
within its consensus nodes,
and only add this concept in its archival nodes (Mirror nodes) -
see [HIP-415: Introduction Of Blocks](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-415).

Therefore Hedera needs an *alternative mechanism* to Ethereum's
to enable it to limit over-reservation of gas.
It has done so by disincentivisation:
​

> In order to prevent over-reservation of the smart contract services the gas credited back relative to the reservation will be limited to at most 20% of the reservation amount.
> From a different perspective the minimum amount of gas charged to a user based on the reservation will be a minimum of 80% of the reservation.
> This will incentivize transaction submitters to get within 25% of the actual gas used in order to not be charged for unused reservation.
> ​
> So the computation for `gasUsed` in Hedera is:
> ​

```
gasUsed = max(gasConsumed, gasLimit * 0.8)
```

​
In other words, `gasLimit` **is** a factor,
when you specify one that is more than actual gas consumed.
​
This is how you get the additional 32,000 `gasUsed`
when you specify an additional 40,000 in `gasLimit`.