# Why does `eth_estimateGas` on Hedera return an unexpectedly high value?

Tags: solidity, rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I am aware that `eth_estimateGas` is not intended to be exact,
but currently, I'm getting actual `gasUsed` values
that are approximately 6% of the value returned by `eth_estimateGas`.

In the following example,
I invoke the same smart contract with the exact same inputs twice, with only 1 difference:

- In the 1st invocation, `gasLimit = eth_estimateGas`
- In the 2nd invocation, `gasLimit = eth_estimateGas * 0.064`

  - This value is a very small fraction of the estimate
  - This value was obtained through trial-and-error ... not through any calculations

```js
    // with exact estimated amount of gas
    const estimatedGas2 = (await expendGasSc.estimateGas.updateState(1_000_000_123n)).toBigInt();
    console.log('estimatedGas2', estimatedGas2);
    const gasLimit2 = estimatedGas2 * 1n;
    console.log('gasLimit2', gasLimit2);
    const txResponse2 = await (await expendGasSc
        .updateState(
            1_000_000_123n,
            { gasLimit: gasLimit2 },
        ))
        .wait();
    const gasUsed2 = txResponse2.gasUsed.toBigInt();
    console.log('gasUsed2', gasUsed2);

    // with small fraction of estimated amount of gas
    const estimatedGas4 = (await expendGasSc.estimateGas.updateState(1_000_000_123n)).toBigInt();
    console.log('estimatedGas4', estimatedGas4);
    const gasLimit4 = estimatedGas4 * 64n / 1000n; // <---  6.4% 
    console.log('gasLimit4', gasLimit4);
    const txResponse4 = await (await expendGasSc
        .updateState(
            1_000_000_123n,
            { gasLimit: gasLimit4 },
        ))
        .wait();
    console.log('txResponse4', txResponse4);
    const gasUsed4 = txResponse4.gasUsed.toBigInt();
    console.log('gasUsed4', gasUsed4);
```

Here are the results:

- When `gasLimit` is 400,000, `gasUsed` is 320,000

  - This is exactly 80% of the specified `gasLimit`,
    indicating that HIP-185's gas over-reservation penalty **is likely* to have kicked in.
  - See [this answer to my previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250742/194982) for context.
- When `gasLimit` is 25,600, `gasUsed` is 23,816

  - This is greater than 80% of the specified `gasLimit`,
    indicating that HIP-185's gas over-reservation penalty **has not** kicked in

```
estimatedGas2 400000n
gasLimit2 400000n
gasUsed2 320000n
estimatedGas4 400000n
gasLimit4 25600n
gasUsed4 23816n
```

Therefore, I am expecting `eth_estimateGas` to return a value
that is much closer to 23,816 than 400,000.
Why is it returning such an unexpectedly high estimate
compared to the actual?

---

Here's the smart contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.18;

contract ExpendSomeGasDemo {
    uint256 public state;

    function updateState(
        uint256 newState
    )
        public
        returns (uint256 updatedState)
    {
        state = newState;
        updatedState = newState;
    }
}
```

Note that this contract is deployed on Hedera Testnet:
[`0x9C58D0159495F7a8853A24574f2B8F348a72424c`](https://hashscan.io/testnet/contract/0.0.4616849)

Note that the Javascript example above is using ethers.js.

Note that this question is a follow up to my previous one:
[Large discrepancy in `gasUsed` values in near-identical transactions on Hedera - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76250641/194982)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're querying `eth_estimateGas` via the Hedera JSON-RPC relay,
which currently uses static values in lieu of actual gas estimation, this is what's responsible for the consistent estimations.

Note, that this will soon be replaced with an actual gas estimation algorithm,
when [the implementation](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-mirror-node/issues/4463)
of [HIP-584: Mirror EVM Archive Node](https://hips.hedera.com/hip/hip-584) is released.
​

Specifically, you can see [`packages/relay/src/lib/constants.ts`](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-json-rpc-relay/blob/ffb51611/packages/relay/src/lib/constants.ts#L69-L73),
to see the the gas-cost-related values defined as constants:
​

```js
{
    // ...
    TX_BASE_COST: 21_000,
    TX_HOLLOW_ACCOUNT_CREATION_GAS: 587_000,
    TX_DEFAULT_GAS_DEFAULT: 400_000,
    TX_CREATE_EXTRA: 32_000,
    TX_DATA_ZERO_COST: 4,
    // ...
}
```

​
These are used by [the `estimateGas` function in `packages/relay/src/lib/eth.ts`](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-json-rpc-relay/blob/ffb51611/packages/relay/src/lib/eth.ts#L436-L464)
in their return values.

Note, that no actual gas estimation algorithm is being run at the moment.
This line - `return this.defaultGas;`, which maps to `TX_DEFAULT_GAS_DEFAULT` above -
is also why you will get the same value of 400,000
anytime you perform `eth_estimateGas` for a smart contract invocation.
Here's the code snippet below
​

```js
  async estimateGas(transaction: any, _blockParam: string | null, requestId?: string) {
    const requestIdPrefix = formatRequestIdMessage(requestId);
    this.logger.trace(`${requestIdPrefix} estimateGas(transaction=${JSON.stringify(transaction)}, _blockParam=${_blockParam})`);
    // this checks whether this is a transfer transaction and not a contract function execution
    if (transaction && transaction.to && (!transaction.data || transaction.data === '0x')) {
      const value = Number(transaction.value);
      if (value > 0) {
        const accountCacheKey = `${constants.CACHE_KEY.ACCOUNT}_${transaction.to}`;
        let toAccount: object | null = this.cache.get(accountCacheKey);
        if (!toAccount) {
          toAccount = await this.mirrorNodeClient.getAccount(transaction.to, requestId);
        }
​
        // when account exists return default base gas, otherwise return the minimum amount of gas to create an account entity
        if (toAccount) {
          this.logger.trace(`${requestIdPrefix} caching ${accountCacheKey}:${JSON.stringify(toAccount)} for ${constants.CACHE_TTL.ONE_HOUR} ms`);
          this.cache.set(accountCacheKey, toAccount);
​
          return EthImpl.gasTxBaseCost;
        }
​
        return EthImpl.gasTxHollowAccountCreation;
      }
​
      return predefined.INVALID_PARAMETER(0, `Invalid 'value' field in transaction param. Value must be greater than 0`);
    } else {
      return this.defaultGas;
    }
  }
​
```